# SOLR search and synonyms

Tags: solr

I have implemented an address search using SOLR and want to replace some text at query time with a space. Eg., if someone enters a word like "undefined" I want it to be replaced by a blank.

`So, 5 Ford Undefined Street becomes 5 Ford  Street`

I have implemented synonyms eg.

```
lt => little
```

How do I go on defining so that at the query time, Undefined translates to a space?

Schema definitions for query is as follows:

```
 <analyzer type="query">
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([,]+)" replacement=" " replace="all"/>      
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>      
    </analyzer>
```

Comment: Couldn't you use a StopFilter with the tokens you want to remove as the wordlist?

Comment: StopFilter works well. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove tokens you can [use the plain old StopFilter](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/filters.html#stop-filter). While most people think of the filter as used for removing non-relevant words such as `the` and `of`, it can be used with any wordlist.

Add `Undefined` (and other words you want to have removed) to a wordlist and add a stopfilter to your analysis chain:

```
<filter name="stop" words="stopwords.txt" />
or
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt"/>
```